# How to find the sum of all entries in the matrix $A^5$

Tags: matrices

> Let $A$ be a $4 × 4$ matrix with non-negative entries such that the sum of the entries in each row of $A$ equals $1$. Find the sum of all entries in the matrix $A^5$.

If $A=I_4$ then $A^5=I_4$ and sum of all entries in the matrix $A^5=4$. But how I show the general result. Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $j=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\\vdots\\1\end{matrix}\right)$. Then  the sum of entries of matrix $A^5$ is just $j^TA^5j$. What can you say about $Aj$?

Comment: I think $Aj=j$. Am I correct?

Comment: @A.D Yes, because $(1,j)$ is an eigenpair of $A$.

Comment: I am sorry...I cant get the concept..will you please explain little more briefly..how will you multiply $A^5$ and $j$.

Comment: @SamChristopher Use the relation : If $( \lambda, v )$ is  Eigen  pair  for  $A$  then $ A^n v = \lambda^n v $ for all $v$